# Why is my if-else statement not working properly?

Tags: java, if-statement

I have the double fields hourlyPayRate and hoursWorked.

I am trying to write a constructor and mutator to have specific conditions, those being to not allow a pay rate less than 7.25 or greater than 25. Do not allow hours worked less than 0 or greater than 70. If a value below the minimum
is passed, then set the field to the minimum. If a value above the maximum is passed, then set the field to the maximum.

With the code I have, the test for it is passing 7.24, and expecting 7.25 and yet my code is returning 7.24. I cannot see why. The test is also checking my mutator by setting the pay to 8.0, then changing it to 7.25 but my code is returning 8.0 without changing, even though it looks like it should return the 7.25 value. What am I doing wrong?

```
public class ProductionWorker extends Employee
{   

private double hourlyPayRate;
private double hoursWorked;

public ProductionWorker(String name, String idNumber, 
String hireDate, ShiftType shift, double hourlyPayRate, double hoursWorked)
{
    super(name, idNumber, hireDate, shift);
    this.hourlyPayRate = hourlyPayRate;
    this.hoursWorked = hoursWorked;

    if (hourlyPayRate > 25)
    {
        hourlyPayRate = 25;
    }
    else if (hourlyPayRate < 7.25)
    {
        hourlyPayRate = 7.25;
    }
    else if (hourlyPayRate < 25 && hourlyPayRate > 7.25)
    {
        this.hourlyPayRate = hourlyPayRate;
    }
    else if (hoursWorked < 0)
    {
        hoursWorked = 0;
    }
    else if (hoursWorked > 70)
    {
        hoursWorked = 70;
    }
}
public double getHourlyPayRate()
{
    return hourlyPayRate;
}


public void setHourlyPayRate(double hourlyPayRate)
{

    //this.hourlyPayRate = hourlyPayRate;

    if (hourlyPayRate > 25)
    {
        hourlyPayRate = 25;
    }
    else if (hourlyPayRate < 7.25)
    {
        hourlyPayRate = 7.25;
    }
    else if (hourlyPayRate < 25 && hourlyPayRate > 7.25)
    {
        this.hourlyPayRate = hourlyPayRate;
    }
}


public double getHoursWorked()
{
    return hoursWorked;
}


public void setHoursWorked(double hoursWorked)
{
    this.hoursWorked = hoursWorked;

    if (hoursWorked < 0)
    {
        hoursWorked = 0;
    }
    else if (hoursWorked > 70)
    {
        hoursWorked = 70;
    }
    else if (hoursWorked > 0 && hoursWorked < 70)
    {
        this.hoursWorked = hoursWorked;
    }
 }
}
```

Also I thought that I was supposed to end if-else statements with just else, but when I do that here the compiler warns me that it isn't a statement?

Comment: This is a bit of a mess, but here's a hint:  be *mindful* of the uses (and lack of uses) of `this`.  Sometimes you're referring to your instance variable.  Sometimes you're referring to your parameter.  Worse, sometimes you're actually assigning things to your parameter, which will be *lost* once you leave the method.

Comment: first question i have is have you went through the debugger and looked at the variables coming through and what is happening? Should be pretty trivial if you take that approach yourself..

Comment: Thanks I'll take a look again. I've been at this for about 4 months now so still getting the basics down while trying to learn new things.

Comment: One would probably create some "ensureValueBetween()" method or something like that

Comment: how come in one of your statements it say  this.hourlyPayRate and the rest are just hourlyPayRate ?

Comment: I think you got confused with block variable and local variable.Local varible has  more scope than block variable.

Comment: Re, "I thought that I was supposed to end if-else statements with just else, but when I do that..."  We can't explain what's wrong with code that you don't show us.  How 'bout you open a second question containing the code that won't compile, _and_ the error message that the compiler gives you.

Comment: You dont have to end if else statements with else, but if you can if you like. it would be if(condition) {do something} else if(condition) {do something} else{do something else}

Comment: [What does your step debugger tell you?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Answer (score 1):

#### Why the final keyword saves you countless time:

Make the following changes and you will understand what is wrong and how to avoid it next time.

```
public ProductionWorker(final String name, 
                        final String idNumber,
                        final String hireDate, 
                        final ShiftType shift, 
                        final double hourlyPayRate, 
                        final double hoursWorked)
```

If you do the above and use a step-debugger you will understand why the correct reference syntax and logic becomes:

```
if (hourlyPayRate > 25) { this.hourlyPayRate = 25; }
else if (hourlyPayRate < 7.25) { this.hourlyPayRate = 7.25; }
else { this.hourlyPayRate = hourlyPayRate; }

if (hoursWorked < 0) { this.hoursWorked = 0; }
else if (hoursWorked > 70) { this.hoursWorked = 70; }
else { this.hoursWorked = hoursWorked; }
```

> [It is really bad practice to put this much logic in a
>   constructor.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7048515/is-doing-a-lot-in-constructors-bad)
>   Ideally you should have done this validation already in some kind of
>   factory method/object pattern implementation. That said you can reduce
>   the code to one liners that are much more explicit about what they are
>   doing and more maintainable in your specific case.

#### In this very specific case:

You can reduce the lines of code by expressing them more succinctly.

```
this.hourlyPayRate = Math.min(Math.max(d,7.25), 25.0);
this.hoursWorked = Math.min(Math.max(d,0.0), 70.0);
```

> Which would not really be onerous to see in a constructor. This is
>   easier to reason about and maintain than a bunch of `if/elseif/else`
>   statements.

#### Use a normalizeToRange function, since both are doing the same thing.

> Note that the `final` keyword here is just as important as the
>   `private` keyword for you to call this method from the `constructor`.

```
private final double normalizeToRange(final double min, final double max, final double d)
{
    return d < min ? min : d > max ? max : d;
}

this.hourlyPayRate = this.normalizeToRange(7.25, 25.0, hourlyPayRate);
this.hoursWorked = this.normalizeToRange(0.0, 70.0, hoursWorked);
```

#### For Complex If/ElseIf/Else chains:

Here is a simplified example of how to apply a [Chain of Responsibility Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern) to eliminate overly long and complex `if/elseif/else` blocks.

> I am sure there will be naysayers that say this is overly complex for
>   this case but I would argue the OP got it wrong enough that this would
>   have let them get it right the first time. This is just a strawman
>   example, illustrating the implementation of the Pattern, The
>   `Constraint` class could be made more generic and more complex with
>   the default logic for `normalize()` in a single place. That and how to
>   apply this is an exercise left for the reader.

```
public class Q43789440
{
    /**
     * Shim/Polyfill for Java < 8 compatibility with Java 8
     *
     * @param <T>
     */
    public interface Predicate<T>
    {
        boolean test(T var1);
    }

    /**
     * Shim/Polyfill for Java < 8 compatibility with Java 8
     *
     * @param <T>
     * @param <F>
     */
    public interface Function<F, T>
    {
        T apply(F var1);

        boolean equals(Object var1);
    }

    public interface Constraint extends Predicate<Double>, Function<Double, Double>
    {
        public Double normalize(final Double input);
    }

    public static class LowerConstraint implements Constraint
    {
        private final Constraint next;

        public LowerConstraint(final Constraint next) { this.next = next; }

        @Override
        public Double normalize(final Double input)
        {
            if (this.test(input)) { return this.apply(input); }
            else { return this.next.normalize(input); }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean test(final Double d)
        {
            return d < 7.25;
        }

        @Override
        public Double apply(final Double d)
        {
            return 7.25;
        }
    }

    public static class UpperConstraint implements Constraint
    {
        private final Constraint next;

        public UpperConstraint(final Constraint next) { this.next = next; }

        @Override
        public Double normalize(final Double input)
        {
            if (this.test(input)) { return this.apply(input); }
            else { return this.next.normalize(input); }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean test(final Double d)
        {
            return d > 25.0;
        }

        @Override
        public Double apply(final Double d)
        {
            return 25.0;
        }
    }

    public static class InRangeConstraint implements Constraint
    {
        @Override
        public Double normalize(final Double input)
        {
            if (this.test(input)) { return this.apply(input); }
            else { throw new IllegalArgumentException(); }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean test(final Double d)
        {
            return d >= 7.25 && d <= 25.0;
        }

        @Override
        public Double apply(final Double d)
        {
            return d;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        final Constraint rules = new LowerConstraint(new UpperConstraint(new InRangeConstraint()));
        for (double d = 0.0; d < 30; d++)
        {
            System.out.printf("%.2f normalized to %.2f", d, rules.normalize(d)).println();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm surprised nobody here mentions something about rounding error problems from using `double` for monetary calculations..

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you find yourself re-writing code, you should create a method. This allows you to just call that method, instead of writing the same code-snippets multiple places. There's also some wrong if/else-statement logic.

Let's take a look at how we can improve your code a little bit, which makes it easier to read and debug!

```
public double hourlyPayRate(double hourlyPayRate) {
    if (hourlyPayRate > 25) {
        hourlyPayRate = 25;
    } else if (hourlyPayRate < 7.25) {
        hourlyPayRate = 7.25;
    }
    return hourlyPayRate;
}

public double hoursWorked(double hoursWorked) {
    if (hoursWorked > 70) {
        hoursWorked = 70;
    } else if (hoursWorked < 0) {
        hoursWorked = 0;
    }
    return hoursWorked;
}
```

The methods first check whether the input is above a certain value and if so,  sets it to that value. Otherwise, it checks to see whether it is below a certain value.
Finally, it returns said value. You don't have to check whether it is in-between the lower and upper range at the end since those tests have already been done.

Comment: this could be expressed as a single method if the `min` and `max` were arguments to the method.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that in the constructor you set the hourlyPayRate and hoursWorked only once.

```
this.hourlyPayRate = hourlyPayRate;
this.hoursWorked = hoursWorked;
```

Here in the if-else statement you are parameter assignment with instance variable assignment. Since the constructor arguments share the same name as the private instance variable. You MUST use the this operator to assign them to the object.

```
public ProductionWorker(String name, String idNumber, 
    String hireDate, ShiftType shift, double hourlyPayRate, double hoursWorked)

{
    super(name, idNumber, hireDate, shift);
    this.hourlyPayRate = hourlyPayRate;
    this.hoursWorked = hoursWorked;

if (hourlyPayRate > 25)
{
    this.hourlyPayRate = 25;
}
else if (hourlyPayRate < 7.25)
{
    this.hourlyPayRate = 7.25;
}
else if (hourlyPayRate < 25 && hourlyPayRate > 7.25)
{
    this.hourlyPayRate = hourlyPayRate;
}
else if (hoursWorked < 0)
{
    this.hoursWorked = 0;
}
else if (hoursWorked > 70)
{
    this.hoursWorked = 70;
}
```

The same issue applies in setHoursWorked(double hoursWorked)

public void setHoursWorked(double hoursWorked)
{
    this.hoursWorked = hoursWorked;

```
if (hoursWorked < 0)
{
    this.hoursWorked = 0;
}
else if (hoursWorked > 70)
{
    this.hoursWorked = 70;
}
else if (hoursWorked > 0 && hoursWorked < 70)
{
    this.hoursWorked = hoursWorked;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (...) {
    doA();
} else if (...) {
    doB();
} else if (...) {
    doC();
}
```

That's never going to do more than one of `doA()`, `doB()`, or `doC()`.

You have two separate constraints on your data:  Rate of pay must be limited to a certain range, and hours worked must be within a certain range.

You won't be able to enforce *both* contstraints with just one `if...else if...else if...` statement.

Comment: this does not address the more fundamental misunderstanding about the scope the variables which would make this part self-evident.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson You're right.  I would rather have made it a comment, but I can't format code in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to understand variable scope. In your methods, `hourlyPayRate` refers to the parameter and `this.hourlyPayRate` refers to the class instance variable. A value assigned to `hourlyPayRate` will be lost once you return from the method.

Your `setHourlyPayRate` mutator should look more like this:

```
public void setHourlyPayRate(double hourlyPayRate)
{
    if (hourlyPayRate > 25)
    {
        this.hourlyPayRate = 25;
    }
    else if (hourlyPayRate < 7.25)
    {
        this.hourlyPayRate = 7.25;
    }
    else
    {
        this.hourlyPayRate = hourlyPayRate;
    }
}
```

This assigns the correct value to the class variable based on the value of the parameter. One way to avoid such confusion is to give different names to your internal variables and your parameters.

The second issue with your code is the `if` .. `else if` statement in your constructor. The `else if` part will only be executed if the previous condition was false. In your case, the `hoursWorked` will only be tested if your `hourlyPayRate` is exactly 25 or 7.25 since those two exact values are not tested in the previous `if` statements.

Comment: Calling instance methods in a constructor is dangerous and should not be suggested as a common practice, because the object is not yet fully initialized (this applies mainly to methods than can be overridden). Also complex processing in constructor is known to have a negative impact on testability.

Comment: You're right, thanks for pointing that out. I updated the answer.

Comment: Naming them different will just cause confusion and maintenance issues. The correct way is to always refer to instance variables with `this.`. You should always use `this.` to eliminate other classes of easy to make mistakes as well.