# Should a C++ constructor that interfaces with hardware do real work?

Tags: c++, constructor, hardware

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How much work should be done in a constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/293967/how-much-work-should-be-done-in-a-constructor)

I'm strugging with some advice I have in the back of my mind but for which I can't remember the reasoning.

I seem to remember at some point reading some advice (can't remember the source) that C++ constructors should not do real work.  Rather, they should initialize variables only.  The advice went on to explain that real work should be done in some sort of init() method, to be called separately after the instance was created.

The situation is I have a class that represents a hardware device.  It makes logical sense to me for the constructor to call the routines that query the device in order to build up the instance variables that describe the device.  In other words, once new instantiates the object, the developer receives an object which is ready to be used, no separate call to object->init() required.

Is there a good reason why constructors shouldn't do real work?  Obviously it could slow allocation time, but that wouldn't be any different if calling a separate method immediately after allocation.

Just trying to figure out what gotchas I not currently considering that might have lead to such advice.

Comment: Possible candidate for merging.

Comment: I nominated this for reopening because the marked duplicate says nothing about hardware, and the very useful answers here are all hardware-relevant.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I remember that Scott Meyers in More Effective C++ recommends against having a superfluous default constructor. In that article, he also touched on using methods liked Init() to 'create' the objects. Basically, you have introduced an extra step which places the responsibility on the client of the class. Also, if you want to create an array of said objects, each of them would have to manually call Init(). You can have an Init function which the constructor can call inside for keeping the code tidy, or for the object to call if you implement a Reset(), but from experiences it is better to delete an object and recreate it rather than try to reset its values to default, unless the objects is created and destroyed many times real-time (say, particle effects).

Also, note that constructors can perform initialization lists which normal functions could not.

One reasons why one may caution against using constructors to do heavy allocation of resources is because it can be hard to catch exceptions in constructors. However, there are ways around it. Otherwise, I think constructors are meant to do what they are supposed to do - prepare an object for its initial state of execution (important for object creation is resource allocation).

Comment: That would be Scott Meyers - Sid Meier is the Civilization guy :)

Answer (score 18):

The one reason not to do "work" in the constructor is that if an exception is thrown from there, the class destructor won't get called.  But if you use RAII principles and don't rely on your destructor to do clean up work, then I feel it's better not to introduce a method which isn't required.

Comment: I would have added that even if a constructor throws every fully constructed member variable will have its derstructor called (thus if you are in the code block of the constructor all members will be correctly destructed).

Comment: How do you do cleanup in your constructor once an exception is thrown?  (Say you allocated a `FILE *` for instance)  **don't rely on your destructor** yet all you can do is let the stack unwind...

Comment: One of your class' member would be a RAII-type object which will close the file* in its destructor.  Something like the FileCloser class from this: http://tomdalling.com/blog/software-design/resource-acquisition-is-initialisation-raii-explained/

Answer (score 9):

Depends on what you mean by real work. The constructor should put the object into a usable state, even if that state is a flag meaning it hasn't yet been initialised :-)

The only rationale I've ever come across for not doing real work would be the fact that the only way a constructor can fail is with an exception (and the destructor won't be called in that case). There is no opportunity to return a nice error code.

The question you have to ask yourself is:

> Is the object usable without calling the `init` method?

If the answer to that is "No", I would be doing all that work in the constructor. Otherwise you'll have to catch the situation when a user has instantiated but not yet initialised and return some sort of error.

Of course, if you can *re-initialise* the device, you should provide some sort of `init` method but, in that case, I would *still* call that method from the constructor if the condition above is met.

Answer (score 7):

In addition to the other suggestions regarding exception handling, one thing to consider when connecting to a hardware device is how your class will handle the situation where a device is not present or communication fails.

In the situation where you can't communicate with the device, you may need to provide some methods on your class to perform later initialization anyway.  In that case, it may make more sense to just instantiate the object and then run through an initialization call.  If the initialization fails, you can just keep the object around and try to initialize communication again at a later time.  Or you may need to handle the situation where communication is lost after initialization.  In either case, you will probably want to think about how you will design the class to handle communication problems in general and that may help you decide what you want to do in the constructor versus an initialization method.

When I've implemented classes that communicate with external hardware, I've found it easier to instantiate a "disconnected" object and provide methods for connecting and setting up initial status.  This has generally provide more flexibility connecting/disconnecting/reconnecting with the device.

Comment: Yes!  Most people don't seem to get this - putting the work in a constructor implicitly ties the success to the lifetime of the object, which doesn't work well for disconnectable objects (such as a "persistent" TCP client).

Comment: I agree. I use an open/close/isOpen interface/paradigm to mark/handle that sort of objects

Answer (score 3):

The only real reason is Testability. If your constructors are full of "real work", that usually means the objects can only be instantiated within a fully initialized, running application. It's a sign the object/class needs further decomposition.

Comment: The testability argument is a good one. But It can probably be handled by mock objects in a majority of cases

Comment: If the constructor makes its own objects, then you can't configure the object with mock objects unless you write a new constructor. Separating the responsibility of making a complex object from setting its member variables gives you the required seam.

Answer (score 3):

When using a constructor and an Init() method you have a source of error. In my experience you will encounter situation where someone forgets to call it, and you might have a subtle bug in your hands. I would say you shouldn't do much work in your constructor but if any init method is needed, then you have a non-trivial construction scenario, and it is about time to look at the creational patterns. A builder function or a factory be wise to have a look at. With a private constructor making sure that no one except your factory or builder function actually build the objects, so you can be sure that it is always constructed correctly.

If your design allow for mistakes in implementation, someone will do those mistakes. My friend Murphy told me that ;)

In my field we work with loads of similar hardware related situations. Factories gives us both testability, security and better ways of failing construction.

Answer (score 2):

It is worth considering lifetime issues and connecting/reconnecting, as Neal S. points out.

If you fail to connect to a device at the other end of a link then it is often the case that the 'device' at your end is usable and will be later if the other end gets its act together.  Examples being network connections etc.

On the other hand if you try and access some local hardware device that does not exist and will never exist within the scope of your program (for example a graphics card that is not present) then I think this is a case where you want to know this in the constructor, so that the constructor can throw and the object can not exist.  If you don't then you may end up with an object that is invalid and will always be so.  Throwing in the constructor means that the object will not exist, and thus functions can't be called on that object.  Obviously you need to be aware of cleanup issues if you throw in a constructor, but if you don't in cases like this then you typically end up with validation checks in all functions that may be called.

So I think that you should do enough in the constructor to ensure you have a valid, usable, object created.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to add my own experience there.

I won't say much about the traditional debate Constructor/Init... for example `Google` guidelines advise against anything the in the Constructor but that's because they advise against Exceptions and the 2 work together.

I can speak about a `Connection` class I use though.

When the `Connection` class is created, it will *attempt* to actually connect itself (at least, if not default constructed). If the `Connection` fails... the object is still constructed and you don't know about it.

When you try to use the `Connection` class you are thus in one of 3 cases:

- no parameter has ever been precised > exception or error code
- the object is actually connected > fine
- the object is not connected, it will attempt to connect > this succeeds, fine, this fails, you get an exception or an error code

I think it's quite useful to have both. However, it means that in every single method actually using the connection, you need to test whether or not it works.

It's worth it though because of disconnection events. When you are connected, you may lose the connection without the object knowing about it. By encapsulating the connection self-check into a `reconnect` method that is called internally by all methods needing a working connection, you really isolate the developers from dealing with the issues... or at least as much as you can since when everything fails you have no other solution that letting them know :)

Answer (score 0):

Doing "real work" in a constructor is best avoided.

If I setup database connections, open files etc inside a constructor and if in doing so one of them raise an exception then it would lead to a memory leak. This will compromise your application's [exception safety](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exception_handling#Exception_safety).

Another reason to avoid doing work in a constructor is that it would make your application less testable. Suppose you are writing a credit-card payment processor. If say in `CreditCardProcessor` class's constructor you do all the work of connecting to a payment gateway, authentate and bill the credit card how do I ever write unit tests for `CreditCardProcessor` class?

Coming to your scenario, if the routines that query the device do not raise any exceptions and you are not going to test the class in isolation then there is its probably preferable to do work in the constructor and avoid calls to that extra `init` method.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple reasons I would use separate constructor/init():

- Lazy/Delayed initialization. This allows you to create the object quickly, fast user response, and delay a more lengthy initialization for later or background processing. This is also a part of one or more design patterns concerning reusable object pools to avoid expensive allocation.
- Not sure if this has a proper name, but perhaps when the object is created, the initialization information is unavailable or not understood by whoever is creating the object (for example, bulk generic object creation). Another section of code has the know-how to initialize it, but not create it.
- As a personal reason, the destructor should be able to undo everything the constructor did. If that involves using internal init/deinit(), no problem, so long as they are mirror images of each other.

Comment: These objectives are more safely achieved by creating an object of a type whose responsibility is to create the real type later. The important thing is that when you have an object of the real type, you know that it's in a safe state to use. Instead of "construct a Thing, then call its init() method, then always have to check you called init()" you have "construct the ThingBuilder, call its createThing() method, then just use your thing"