# Error when passing arguments to pthread_create()

Tags: c++, macos, arguments, pthreads

I am trying to create a Thread-Pool-like structure for `pthread`s to do identical jobs for network programming, which is very similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11258725/can-pthreads-be-created-inside-a-constructor). However, a problem occurred as I tried to pass the arguments of the `init()` method to `pthread_create()`.

### Code

```cpp
class ThreadPool{
    public:
        BlockingQueue socket_bq;
        pthread_mutex_t* threads[THREAD_NUM];   // store the pointer of threads

        ThreadPool();
        void init(pthread_attr_t* attr, void*start_routine(void*), void* arg);
};

void ThreadPool::init(pthread_attr_t* attr, void*start_routine(void*), void* arg){
    // create threads
    for(int i = 0; i < THREAD_NUM; i++){
        if(pthread_create(threads[i], attr, start_routine, arg)!=0){
            fprintf(stderr, "Thread Pool Init: falied when creatng threads");
            exit(1);
        }
    }
}
```

### Error message

```
error: no matching function for call to 'pthread_create'
        if(pthread_create(threads[i], attr, start_routine, arg)!=0){
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/pthread.h:329:5: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'pthread_mutex_t *' (aka '_opaque_pthread_mutex_t *') to 'pthread_t  _Nullable * _Nonnull' (aka '_opaque_pthread_t **') for 1st argument
int pthread_create(pthread_t _Nullable * _Nonnull __restrict,
    ^
1 error generated.
```

Comment: You're passing a `pthread_mutex_t *` as the first parameter.  It should be a [`pthread_t *`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_create.3.html).

Comment: Thanks @G.M., it solves the problem!

Comment: Since C++11, you really should be using `std::thread` instead of `pthreads` directly.

Comment: Hi, @RemyLebeau thank you for your advice! But since this is a school assignment and the lecturer insisted that we should use the `pthread` provided by the OS, I guess I'll just have to live with it for a while. I'll definitely use `std::thread` in my future projects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition of `threads` is incorrect. It should be:

```
pthread_t* threads[THREAD_NUM];
```