# FILE*, fopen_s, and initialization lists

Tags: c++, initialization-list

I have a class declared like this (only relevant parts shown):

```
class X
{
  public:
     X(int x);

  private:
     FILE *stream;
     int _x;
}
```

The constructor opens a file:

```
X::X(int x) : _x(x)
{
   int err = fopen_s(&stream, "myfile.txt", "w");
   fputs("some text", stream);
   ...
}
```

It is used in another class like so:

```
class Y
{
   public:
      Y();

   private:
      X myX;
}
```

In the constructor of Y, myX is initialized via the initialization list and a method is invoked upon it:

```
Y::Y() : myX(100)
{
   myX.init();
}
```

When I step through the constructor of X, the stream is allocated and written to without error. If I put a breakpoint at the opening brace of the constructor of Y, stream has the same value as during the constructor of X. When I step into the body of Y's constructor, however, the value of stream changes and the next use of it (e.g. in init()) causes an access violation. Everything works fine if I change Y to store a pointer to X instead of a direct reference and allocate X on the heap. I suspect it has something to do with where fopen_s is allocating the FILE*, but I cannot confirm this. Can anyone explain why this fails?

Comment: You should show Init() also, consider not doing work in your constructor and add an Init to Y that would then call Init on its X (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/293967/how-much-work-should-be-done-in-a-constructor)

Comment: Does the error persist if you do a clean rebuild?

Comment: side bar: identifiers (variable names, types, macro definitions, etc.) with leading underscores are reserved by the implementation you're compiling against. I.e. `_x` is a bad habit and you should break it now while you're learning. `x_`, `x`, etc. are all perfectly fine.

Comment: Also, just for kicks, if you need to do that in your constructor, then declare the default constructor for X private so you can't accidentally create an X with an invalid FILE* in there.